# XQuartz disk image won't open

Tags: install, dmg

Every time I try to open the .dmg to install XQuartz, a window pops up saying `the following disk images couldn't be opened` and the reason shown is `not recognized`. I don't know if I need another application to open it or if the file is corrupted, or if it's some other problem entirely.

Comment: Are you on Mountain Lion?  is gatekeeper on?

Comment: [What do I do if the disk image data is corrupted?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110026/8546) (2013-11-10)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the file downloaded is corrupted, you should be able to open the .dmg by simply double clicking it (I downloaded XQuartz a couple of days ago and could open the .dmg without a problem).

Unfortunately, the download page doesn't provide a checksum to check against, so I'll provide the one I generated:

> 98b2ca8580046d5b91250c5a244c8182437dc9d7

**This checksum uniquely identifies the XQuarz .dmg.**

You can generate a checksum of XQuartz on your Mac like this (from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1652):

1. Open Terminal (in `/Application/Utilities`)
2. Type:

   `openssl sha1 ~/Downloads/XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg`

   (adapt to the path where `XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg` was downloaded)
3. Compare the number you get with the number above. If they are different, the file is corrupted.